# Avoiding ambiguity with Netrunner tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Following the re-release of Netrunner under the Android franchise, I expect to see more questions about it. There are two tags for the two editions ([netrunner](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netrunner) and [android-netrunner](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-netrunner)), but **is it worth renaming the "netrunner" tag to "netrunner-ccg" (or something else) to remove all ambiguity and avoid questions being incorrectly tagged?**

If so, and as a separate question, **is it worth having a generic "netrunner" tag for release-independent questions?** That is, questions about Netrunner at large, but not restricted to either edition? It may be that such questions are too rare to worry about, although the fact that I wanted to ask one is what brought me here!

Comments? Opinions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, most tags should be game specific. Few if any questions should be generic enough to cross over multiple game titles. A few examples might be something like:

- What is the history of the Catan games?
- How does each version of Cosmic Encounter differ from each other? Are all expansions compatible with each version?
- Can I use the Daily Actions from one D&D board game in another?

These types of questions that ask for answers within a particular universe are fairly rare, with perhaps one or two questions only. Unfortunately, with only one question, a tag will disappear. Truthfully, many of these questions could just list 4-5 games that the game is referencing, or focus on the game that they are interested in.

Comment: Um... you can't create a synonym. But you can retag the existing questions manually to [tag:netrunner-ccg] (which I see you have done).

Comment: @ire_and_curses, yeah I figured that out when.the system blocked me. It complained that both tags (or one) needed 5+ upvotes. I suppose we will need more questions before a synonym can be made.

Answer (score 0):

Netrunner defies the standard naming situation. It was originally put out by Wizards of the Coast and set in a generic universe. More recently it was revived, the rules and game concepts were transferred almost exactly (with a few minor adjustments and a couple major ones) and the game was set in a currently fleshed-out game-world with everything from board games to RPG's set in the same world. There are still people playing the old game, with fan-based card sets being developed and authorized for tournament play still, but the new system is out and being run by a completely different gaming company and it's not using a [CCG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collectible_card_game) concept but an [LCG](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_npm.asp?eidm=14).

So I would think that [android-netrunner](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-netrunner) and [netrunner-ccg](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netrunner-ccg) and [netrunner](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netrunner) would probably allow for all specific sets of questions. Of course... I am new here to Stackexchange still and learning my around still.